# Textsize in theorem environment

Tags: theorems

Can I change the size in theorem environments? If applicable, how can I change the text not to be cursive?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries,size=\small}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!20!bg}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{beisp}{Beispiel}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
{%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  }%
 }

 \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
 }
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}

 \begin{beisp}[Konsumausgaben eines Haushalts]
This is the beginning of Theorem 1.
\end{beisp} 

 \end{frame} 
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a proposal.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}

\setbeamerfont{block title}{series=\bfseries,size=\small}
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{bg=gray!20!bg}

\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\newtheorem{beisp}{Beispiel}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}{%
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{0.7\textwidth}
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
{%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx\inserttheoremaddition\@empty\else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi%
  }%
  \normalfont\small % <- I only added this line
 }

 \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{%
\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
 }
 \makeatother

 \begin{document}

  \begin{frame}

 \begin{beisp}[Konsumausgaben eines Haushalts]
This is the beginning of Theorem 1.
\end{beisp} 

 \end{frame} 
 \end{document}
```

For risks and side effects, ask your pharmacist or doctor. ;-)